# Javascript MySQL What does insert return

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In my script I execute my inserts like this

```
sql ="INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES ("values")
connection.query(sql, function(error, rows, fields)
```

rows.InsertId seems to contain one of the inserted rows but I don't know if its the first or the last row inserted

this is the mysql node.js implementation I'm using, the documentation only says this.

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: `sql ="INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES ("values")` should be `sql ="INSERT INTO \`table\` (fields) VALUES ('values')`

Comment: `InsertID` contains the last inserted row

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that sensitive if the table names and values meet certain constraints but my example was just to explain my question further without complicating it with my actual parameters since my tables are more complex.